# SSH Host-based authentication: How can SSH client force to use given key location

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

Linux man page on [ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) say about host based authentication works as `SSH server must be able to verify the client's host key (see the description of /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts and ~/.ssh/known_hosts, below) for login to be permitted.` Which I understand `~/.ssh/known_hosts` contain host keys of SSH server accessed by client.

As such in Key-based authentication where identity private keys are read from `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, how can I force to look for keys in different location in host based authentication with only key `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

In key based auth. we can point to a different location using `ssh -i /new/path/to/id_rsa <server IP>`, and would like to know how it is feasible with host based auth.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `known_hosts` files is used by your ssh client to verify the identity of the remote host to which you are connecting.  In host-based authentication, the *remote* server needs to verify the identity of your client host, which has nothing to do with your local `known_hosts` file.

Your host key comes from `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` or one of the other similarly named files in `/etc/ssh`.  You set the location of your hostkey using the `HostKey` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Note that this cannot be set *per connection*.  This is a credential that identifies *your host*.

Comment: All that is true.  But I think the OP still has a valid question, for all that it's not very clearly expressed: where does the server cache the client's host key, and can that be changed?

Comment: I didn't actually see that in the question.  In any case, the answer is that the remote host will look up the host key in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`, which must be maintained by a system administrator.

Comment: I agree I rather inferred the question, but that's how I read it.  Anyway, you answered mine (+1 for you!) so hopefully you've also answered his/hers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not feasible with host-based auth. Host-based auth relies on `ssh-keysign` which has hard-coded locations of the host keys. In particular, for openssh-6.2p1, in ssh-keysign.c there is:

```
170   key_fd[i++] = open(_PATH_HOST_DSA_KEY_FILE, O_RDONLY);
171   key_fd[i++] = open(_PATH_HOST_ECDSA_KEY_FILE, O_RDONLY);
172   key_fd[i++] = open(_PATH_HOST_RSA_KEY_FILE, O_RDONLY);
```